# vue3 resuable computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, computed-properties

I tried creating Singleton service files with vue3 to have reusable computed properties (define once , then just reuse on every other call)

Normally with composition api pattern each time you do `useX()` every computed property inside is is redefined, this is ok for small project with little amount of computed props but for my scenario many computed props are reused on multiple components

so here what I did :

```
function factory(){
 const x = computed(()=> store.getters['x']);

 function updateX(){
   store.commit('setX',newXValue);
 }

 return { x };
}

export default function useY() {
  return SingletonServiceProvider.Create<ReturnType<typeof factory>>(factory);
}
```

```
export default class SingletonServiceProvider {
  static Create<T>(factory: (...args: unknown[]) => T): T {
    // TODO define proper type
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!factory.Instance) {
      // @ts-ignore
      factory.Instance = factory();
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    return factory.Instance;
  }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing: the `x` prop is properly filled the first time. But If I change the store value the `x` computed property is not updated!!!
I even added a `store.watch` and even this is nor triggered too!!

```
  store.watch(
    (state, getters) => getters['x'],
    (value, oldValue) => {
      console.log('...................xxxxx', { ...value }, { ...oldValue });
    },
  );
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a vue/vuex limit ?

Comment: Your factory doesn't return anything

Comment: Hmmm; but even if it did, neither does change the value in the store. Considering the watcher on the store does not fire, it means that the getter (which is technically a computed property as well) does not detect a change in the things it relies on. Whatever `getters['x']` relies on is likely not reactive.

Comment: @Sumurai8 that factory is just a sample , it does return the `x` and `x` has been used in other component, and the value is store is being updated , I set a log on the mutation that updates this value and it works as expected, the problem is that this computed `x` is only updated once!

Comment: I suggest you migrate your app to [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html) which is now the official state management of vuejs. Getter in Pinia is truly a reuseable computed property (not like vuex in vue3)